# How to capture Response Body in variable using POSTMAN when there is only value in response body and no field name

Tags: rest, postman

How to capture Response Body in variable  using POSTMAN when there is only value in response body and no field name

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the request body as text using `pm.response.text()`:

```
pm.test("Body matches string", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("string_you_want_to_search");
});
```

This code example comes straight from Postman's documentation which has some particularly useful examples of [request handling](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test-examples/#response-handling).